# Im making a story that has an angry god getting mad at modern technology and erased it. How much time would it take to get back to now?

Tags: space

I know this has probably been asked before but I'm curious. And, this will likely have no set answer and we wouldnt know. 
I would assume that a *lot* of the information would lost. Though people can write it down in stone or paint or just aligning rocks if it has to come to that.
(This post was edited to fit the guidelines and such, I forgot to mention the actual storybuilding)

Comment: I'm not sure that I see the Worldbuilding element. This seems more like a god-at-play thought experiment. (Hint: Most folks won't worship you anymore, since a just god wouldn't do that. You just became the *evil* paragon in the new pantheon).

Comment: What does "starting with sticks and stones" actually mean, especially in the context of "retaining the knowledge we have today"? I would think that the two are incompatible...

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding Kamm, you can [edit] your question to fit with the requirements of being on-topic as laid-out in the [help], it'll then be elligible to e re-opened.

Comment: As it stands this seems (IMO) to be both *opinion based* and too much like asking people to create a plot for you - both reasons to close a question.

Comment: @Tantalus'touch. Thank you for your critique, I have edited it

Comment: @StephenG That wasn't the intention, though I do see why you think that. I already have the setting and plots laid out

Answer (score 2):

10,000 years.  Just like it did last time...

The stone age ended [approximately 10,700 years ago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_Age) and since then, humanity has slowly mastered the skills necessary to reach space.  So, as a base line, the journey can be completed in about 10,000 years.

You have added one new factor to this proven base line and that is that the first generation of stone aged people have the knowledge we have today.

It is my belief that that additional knowledge will have very little positive effect on the length of the journey because most of that first generation will be coming into their new stone age life style without the physical fitness or practical knowledge to survive without the conveniences of modern technology.  Massive starvation and conflict over what little resources can be scrounged from the natural world will leave those unlucky first generation survivors with no opportunity to educate their children in the many esoteric sciences which will have no direct effect on those children's survival.  The luck children will be tough whatever stone age skills their parents have figured out since the transition.  Within a few generations, all detailed knowledge of science will be lost.  A few generations after that, even the memory of that there was a thing called science would fade away.

Thus begins the long journey back to the stars...  with no significant advantages over the last time we traveled it.

Comment: I don't think it would be hard for this first generation to teach alphabetic script & positional notation for numbers to the 2nd generation. Just retaining those would speed up other progress a lot. Writing those on clay tablets would be clumsy compared to paper, but probably the best initially available & much better than nothing

Comment: Thank you! Although this wasn't what I was exactly hoping for it did help me. Though I have edited the post now :P